# Flatroof DYI vent in a maximum

Tags: ventilation, roofing, venting

My flat roof has just been redone by professionals. Before, I had a lot of mold in my attic (more of a crawl space), so we added a second maximum (now I have 2 of https://ventilation-maximum.com/en/products/flat-roof-ventilators/vmax-102/).

Next week, a company will come and remove all the mold in my attic. They need to remove all the gypsum panels in my attic because I have no access and only 19 inches of space between my ceiling and roof.

My question is, if I DIY a fan in my maximum with a 200mm computer fan and a solar panel outside, will it help remove excess moisture on hot days? If yes, should the fan pull in fresh air or push out moisture?

Thank you, and I hope I am clear!

Answer (score 1):

A single 200mm fan will do just fine to remove heat from your computer case that is 2-3 square feet (and probably no more than 2-3 cubic feet).

According to the link *you* posted one vent will remove the appropriate amount of heat/moisture from "100 to 150 ft<sup>2</sup>".

Add the fan if it makes you feel better, but, more importantly, measure your roof, calculate the square footage, then divide by 100 and by 150, and make sure you're somewhere in the right range of vents.

If you're not, call back whoever installed the roof - they should have done this math for you. If you're in the right range, you're good to go.